# Entity Framework equivalent query in Laravel PHP

Tags: laravel, entity-framework, .net-core

Please help me make a filter similar to this in Laravel.

```
var AutosVolks = context.Cars.Include(x => x.Brand).Where(x => x.Brand.Name == "Volkswagen").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) as such:

```
$AutoVolks = Cars::with('brands')->whereHas('brands',
               function(Builder $q) {
                  $q->where('name', '=', 'Volkswagen')
               })->get();
```

Assuming the model name `Cars` has relationship named `brands`.